# How to make Elasticsearch case-insensitive without changing the existing documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I am a beginner in Elasticsearch and I am working on a project where the requirement is to look for field values that ought to start with the pattern that has been provided.

I'm using a wildcard for the search pattern in this case. (Eg: `Ste.*`).

Additionally, I am using the `_msearch` option to search across multiple fields.

I want the matching records and also the count of matching records. I am using aggregate to get the count.

However, there are no issues when searching for numerical values. When I search for String, then there is a case-sensitive issue. When I search for `Ste`, I can see results such as Stephen, Steven, and Stella.

When I search for `ste` in Lowercase, nothing returns.

Below is the script that I tried:

```
import logging
import os
import json
import boto3
import requests
import elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch


ES_Index_Name = 'emp_details_1_1'
ES_Cluster_IP = 'localhost'


def lambda_handlet(event):
    ES_URL = f'http://{ES_Cluster_IP}:9200/{ES_Index_Name}/_msearch'
    print("URL - ", ES_URL)
    query_input = event

    query_input_star = '.*'
    query_input_re = query_input + query_input_star

    searchString = [ {"index": "emp_details_1_1"},
                     {"_source":[],"size":0,"min_score":1,"query":{"prefix":{"firstname.keyword":query_input}},"aggs":{"firstname":{"terms":{"field":"firstname.keyword","include":query_input_re}},"firstname_count":{"value_count":{"field":"firstname.keyword"}}}},
                     {"index": "emp_details_1_1"},
                     {"_source":[],"size":0,"min_score":1,"query":{"prefix":{"phone.keyword":query_input}},"aggs":{"phone":{"terms":{"field":"phone.keyword","include":query_input_re}},"phone_count":{"value_count":{"field":"phone.keyword"}}}}]
    searchQuery = ""    
    for d in searchString:
        searchQuery += json.dumps(d) + "," + "\n"
        print("API Global search fn: ",d)

    print("searchQuery: ", searchQuery)

    headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json","Accept":"test/plain"}
    searchResponse = requests.get(url=ES_URL, headers=headers, data=searchQuery)
    print("API Global response: ", json.loads(searchResponse.text))


lambda_handlet('M')
```

Also below is the mapping for the index:

```
{
  "emp_details_1_1" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "firstname" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "phone" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the sample output:

```
{'took': 190, 'responses': [{'took': 190, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': {'value': 3, 'relation': 'eq'}, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}, 'aggregations': {'firstname': {'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0, 'sum_other_doc_count': 0, 'buckets': [{'key': 'Masha', 'doc_count': 1}, {'key': 'Millard', 'doc_count': 1}, {'key': 'Monte', 'doc_count': 1}]}, 'firstname_count': {'value': 3}}, 'status': 200}, {'took': 20, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': {'value': 0, 'relation': 'eq'}, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}, 'aggregations': {'phone_count': {'value': 0}, 'phone': {'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0, 'sum_other_doc_count': 0, 'buckets': []}}, 'status': 200}]}
```

How can I modify my script so that the search would perform case-insensitive searches regardless of whether I pass lowercase or uppercase strings?

Answer (score 0):

Add case_insensitive param, the feature is supported after  [7.10.0]

```
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
            "firstname.keyword": {
                "value": "ste",
                "case_insensitive": true
            }
        }
    }
```